# Fortify - Access control: database

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, fortify

I am currently using VB WebForms for web development, but I've encountered a persistent issue that I can't seem to resolve after scanning with Fortify. I'm using the SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer function to write a DataTable, but this function is consistently detected as having an 'Access Control: database' risk. I'm unsure how to modify this to mitigate the risk.

I've tried using a solution with SQL commands, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.

I've also tried using regular expressions to check the contents of the dataTable, but I still can't eliminate this risk.

Comment: Fortify (and other static code analysis tools) aren't perfect which is why they have ways to mark issues as false positive. If you are sure, and have (automated) tests that can prove your remedies fix the issue, then mark it as a false positive and move on.